# Macro does not execute completely

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a macro that Archives: it selects rows with the right cell value and move them to another tab (while deleting the rows in the tab of origin).

My macro was working perfectly fine, but I decided to change my file and have different new tabs. When I computed my Macro in my new tabs, and it works on the right rows, and deletes them, but does not copy them in my "Archive tab" :

```
 Sub Archive_Ongoing()

Test 2 : works for 2 arguments.

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("B90_Projects_OnGoing").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("B90_Projects_Archived").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("B90_Projects_Archived").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("B90_Projects_OnGoing").Range("O1:O" & I)
    Set yRg = Worksheets("B90_Projects_OnGoing").Range("T1:T" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Closed" And CStr(yRg(K).Value) <> "" Then
            xRg(K).Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("B90_Projects_Archived").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Closed" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub'
```

Any one would be able to explain why?

Comment: `xRg(K).Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("B90_Projects_Archived").Range("A" & J + 1)` is attempting to copy a Selection and you don't have anything selected in your code... Unless you're manually selecting it and then running the macro?

Comment: remove `On Error Resume Next` and debug your code line-by-line, you'll find out **very quickly** what your issue is. If you can't solve update your question with something more specific (i.e. - line of error and what you have tried to solve issue). You also need to loop backwards through a range when also deleting rows from the range.

Comment: this line `xRg(K).Selection.Copy ....` throws error 438 .... your code cannot possibly work because of it

Answer (score 0):

Because you're decrementing your `K` variable within the FOR loop, which is also incrementing it.  Your K variable never changes.  Comment out `K = K - 1` and report back?

If you're doing that on purpose to evaluate / delete a single line and shift the next values up then you might want to have a `K2` variable that you increment like this:

```
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K - K2).Value) = "Closed" And CStr(yRg(K - K2).Value) <> "" Then
        xRg(K - K2).Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("B90_Projects_Archived").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K - K2).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(K - K2).Value) = "Closed" Then
            K2 = K2 + 1
        End If
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
```